# Image properties in XCode inspector does not show size for images

Tags: xcode, png

I'm curious why right-hand property inspector window Xcode does not show the dimensions and resolution for my PNG images when i select an image (the image preview works just fine). The Image Properties shows "--" (double dash) for each property as in this screenshot:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g1WD.png)

[image: Property editor screenshot]

ps. I use Xcode 4.3.3 and Lion 10.7.4

Comment: I have the same issue on XCode 4.5.1 I assume there is some metadata missing from the image file itself, but haven't tracked it down.